# Cannot pass object data to modal

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

having an issue with passing object data to modal, the modal and cards show up fine with correct data, but once I click the card the model does not display its corresponding data, they each have there own object data as so:

```
export const projectObjOne = {
id: "projects",

topLine: "Project 1",
headline: "React, JS, Node",
description: "",

img: "/images/Aucklandbanner.png",
alt: "project-one",

buttonLabel: "Button 1",
buttonLabelTwo: "Button 2",
};

export const projectObjTwo = {
id: "projects",

topLine: "Project 2",
headline: "React, JS, Node",
description: "",

img: "/images/Aucklandbanner.png",
alt: "project-one",

buttonLabel: "Button 1",
buttonLabelTwo: "Button 2",
};
```

Now here is my index with the cards and modal hook:

```
const Projects = ({}) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  // const [modalInfo, setModalInfo] = usestate([]),

  const openModal = () => {
    setShowModal(!showModal);

    console.log("clicked");
  };

  const projectData = {};

  return (
    <>
      <ProjectsContainer id="projects">
        <ProjectsWrapper>
          <div onClick={openModal}>
            <ProjectCard {...projectObjOne} />
            <ProjectModal
              showModal={showModal}
              setShowModal={setShowModal}
              {...projectObjOne}
            />
          </div>

          <div onClick={openModal}>
            <ProjectCard {...projectObjTwo} />
            <ProjectModal
              showModal={showModal}
              setShowModal={setShowModal}
              {...projectObjTwo}
            />
          </div>

          <div onClick={openModal}>
            <ProjectCard {...projectObjThree} />
            <ProjectModal
              showModal={showModal}
              setShowModal={setShowModal}
              {...projectObjTwo}
            />
          </div>
        </ProjectsWrapper>
      </ProjectsContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

So when I click the card only the spread operator for the first objects data shows, any of the others won't show its corresponding data as it should.

Cheers

Comment: On Project Modal 3 you're spreading `projectObjTwo`. Is that your mistake? What do you mean by the "first objects" show?

Comment: yes thats a mistake but it still will only display the first one passed in the first modal ...projectObjOne on every modal it wont update and show ...projectObjTwo on the next card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `showModal` variable for all modals. Modal second and third might be there but they're overlaped, one solution would be make an object with the different modals or simply use a variable for each modal.

```
const Projects = ({}) => {
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState({ first: false, second: false, third: false});

const openModal = (modalName) => {
   setShowModal({ ...showModal, [modalName]: !showModal[modalName] });
};
...

<div onClick={() => openModal('first')}>
        <ProjectCard {...projectObjOne} />
        <ProjectModal
          showModal={showModal['first']}
          setShowModal={setShowModal}
          {...projectObjOne}
        />
</div>
```

Comment: ok so ive done that and replicated it three times changed it to objone two three so on... but it only renders the last divs objectThree when you click the card if you understand what i mean